# How can I make to show ONLY the resources working?

Tags: anylogic

I have created an schedule, named "schedule", defined by these characteristics:

- Type: integer value.
- The schedules defines: intervals.
- Duration type: week.

I also created a "workers" Resource Pool:

- Type: moving.
- Capacity defined: by shift plan.
- Shift group sizes: 3 sizes + 0 (breaks in each shift).
- Schedule of shift group IDs: schedule

The first group has 10 workers, the second 10 and the third 7. However, when I run the model I see all the 27 workers (10+10+7) are already in the model, although only the specified number of workers work.

Do you know how can I make that only the required workers are shown in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Shift plans *do* work by only showing (having agents in existence) the resources which are currently on-shift, so there may be some problem with your setup.

> Shift group sizes: 3 sizes + 0 (breaks in each shift).

What does the "+0" mean here? If you have 3 shifts (IDs 1,2,3 in the Schedule) you should be specifying these as `{10, 10, 7}`. And the Schedule should have a default value of -1 (see the example in the Resource Pool help page on shift plans).

I suspect you have put a default value of 0 for the Schedule and then included a zero entry (so `{10, 10, 7, 0}` or `{0, 10, 10, 7}`) which doesn't do what you want (though that doesn't exactly result in what you're saying in my experience).

If this isn't the problem, it may be the way you've defined the breaks; post info on that.

Answer (score -1):

Change the visibility of the animation of your workers when they change state in the resource pool.

1. define your own agent type for the resources (if not already done)
2. create some animation for the resource (if not already done)
3. in the resource pool properties, use code as below (assuming there is a `myRectangle` shape in your resource agent type):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In this way what happens is that only the workers doing a task are shown, but not the others of the same group if they are not working. Anyway, definately it was an improvement!!

Comment: Hi @Manu_CS please upvote the response if it was helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote. Feel free to ask follow-up questions in new issues :)